# Exception has occurred: ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 3) when attempting to unpack an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to speed up keypoint detection by pre-generating the keypoints of the objects I want to detect before passing them into FLANN for detection.

I'm getting the keypoints and descriptors but when I try and select them with `keypoint_needle =  needle_kp1_desc[0]` and `descriptors_needle = needle_kp1_desc[1]` I'm expecting `keypoint_needle` to be a KeyPoint value like: `<KeyPoint 000001EEFF0CB5A0>` and `descriptors_needle` to be an array while I'm actually getting both as KeyPoint values.

I thought `[0]` would select array column/list (unsure what it's called when multiple lists are appended to the same array) item 0 and `[1]` would select column/list item 1 as in the below image.

But it looks like I'm getting object 1 and 2 from `0`. How do I reference object `1` if not with `[1]`

[image]

```
def loadImages(directory):
    image_list = []
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        image_list.append(img)
    return image_list

def preProcessNeedle(image_list):
    needle_kp1_desc = []
    for i in image_list:
        orb = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=32)
        keypoints_needle, descriptors_needle = orb.detectAndCompute(i, None)
        needle_kp1_desc.append((keypoints_needle, descriptors_needle))
    return needle_kp1_desc

def kpDetection(needle_kp1_desc):
    # Object Detection
    for i in needle_kp1_desc:
        keypoint_needle = needle_kp1_desc[0]
        descriptors_needle = needle_kp1_desc[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're iterating over elements in your `needle_kp1_desc`, but you never do anything with `i`. Try:

```py
def kpDetection(needle_kp1_desc):
    # Object Detection
    for i in needle_kp1_desc:
        keypoint_needle = i[0]
        descriptors_needle = i[1]
```

Note, you should also find a more descriptive name for `i`.

Comment: Been a long day, thank you. Shouldn't have missed that!